# "You may need an appropriate loader for this file type", webpack can't parse angular2 file

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I'm trying to get a very simple Angular2 app working, with Webpack as a module bundler. I'm following [this code](https://github.com/johnlindquist/intro-to-angular2), and I copied all the configuration files as they are, only changing file paths. However, when I run `npm-start`, I get the following error, which I think is a Webpack error:

```
ERROR in ./hello.js
Module parse failed: /home/marieficid/Documentos/cloud/cloud/hello.js Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";
| import {Component} from "angular2/core";
| 
 @ ./app.ts 2:0-21
```

As a result, the Angular2 code in my app isn't loaded.

This is my `app.ts`:

```
import "./hello.js";
```

This is `hello.js`, where the error seems to be (which I take to mean that webpack parsed app.ts just fine):

```
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";
import {Component} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: '<div>Hello world</div>'
})
class App{}

bootstrap(App);
```

And this is`webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'app': './app.ts',
    'vendor': './vendor.ts'
  },
  output: {
    path: "./dist",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js'),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: false,
      template: './index.html'
    })       
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
    ],
    noParse: [ path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'angular2', 'bundles') ]
  },

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

All these files and `node_modules` are in the same directory.

I have found similar questions online but nothing worked for me. I also didn't install babel because the sample code I'm using as base doesn't use it, but if it's necessary I'm will.

Comment: You have `ts-loader` only in your `loaders`. Webpack is trying to do something with the `js` file, but founds no loader for it. The simplest thing you can do is remove the `js` files.

Comment: What do you mean remove the `js` files? I wouldn't be able to build an Angular2 app without them, would I?

Comment: Webpack can read `ts` files (that's what `ts-loader` is for) and bundle everything for you in a js file, you don't need to write the code in js files. Now, if you want to you should add `script-loader` if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Hey, your suggestion worked! Do you want to submit it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @napstablook

Since in your webpack.config.js file you have

```
resolve: {
   extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
},
```

Webpack will try to handle those `.js` files but it needs a specific loader to do so which is, if I'm not wrong, [`script-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader).

In your case the solution is as simple as deleting the `.js` files, or changing their extension to be `.ts`.

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue occurred when I ran **ng test**,
please check below points,

- Console will list out the files that is causing the error.
- Check the html file is correctly mapped from the typescript.
- styleUrls file should point to the  CSS file not html, this is the mistake I
  did.

Answer (score 0):

this error also comes up for me in angular forms when i had patch value set then an extra = sign
ncont.controls[position].patchValue({[cardname]:file}) = file
which is a dumb part on me and angular for not telling me