# Karma throws "Module parse failed" when reading typescript

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack, single-spa

Repo with an example: https://github.com/OriolInvernonLlaneza/karma-webpack-error-example

I had Karma + Jasmine tests running correctly with Angular 11 and Webpack 4. However, when trying to update Angular and Webpack to v12 and v5, I'm getting stuck on the following error when launching the tests:

[image]

This is my Karma conf:

```js
module.exports = (config) => {
  config.set({
    // ... normal karma configuration

    // make sure to include webpack as a framework
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'webpack'],

    plugins: [
      'karma-webpack',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine-html-reporter',
      'karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter',
      'karma-sourcemap-loader',
    ],

    files: [
      // all files ending in ".spec.ts"
      // !!! use watched: false as we use webpacks watch
      { pattern: './src/**/*.spec.ts', watched: false }
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      // add webpack as preprocessor
      "**/*.ts": ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },

    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,

    webpack: {
      externals: [
        /^@example\/*/,
      ],
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    }
  });
}
```

And my Webpack conf:

```js
const singleSpaAngularWebpack = require('single-spa-angular/lib/webpack').default
    const path = require('path');
    
    module.exports = (angularWebpackConfig, options) => {
      const singleSpaWebpackConfig = singleSpaAngularWebpack(angularWebpackConfig, options);
        
      singleSpaWebpackConfig.externals = [
        /^@example\/*/,
      ];
    
      singleSpaWebpackConfig.condig.resolve.extensions = ['', '.ts', '.js']

      singleSpaWebpackConfig.module.rules = [
          { test: /\.ts$/, use: ['angular2-template-loader', 'ts-loader'], exclude: './node_modules' },
          { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader', exclude: './node_modules' }
      ];
}
```

I also tried with the custom rules I had before and got the same error.

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

Here's the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.3",
    "angular-i18next": "^10.3.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "i18next": "^20.3.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "single-spa": "~5.9.3",
    "single-spa-angular": "~5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "12",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.1.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^16.4.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^4.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-source-map-support": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions"]
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
}
```

Update:
I changed the test framework to Jest as I couldn't find the fix for this.

Comment: You may want to to check this question, which looks similar to me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990003/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-for-this-file-type-webpack-cant-parse-ang

Comment: I added the resolve.extensions array and babel-loader for JS. Still get the same error. Will edit the question.

Comment: What version of `ts-loader` have you got installed? Could you share your `package.json` as well please?

Comment: Added the package.json :)

Comment: Could you please update the question with the `.babelrc` content?

Comment: .babelrc added :)

Comment: I noticed your using 2 loaders, can you try using only `ts-loader` ? as I think it might be breaking on the `angular2-template-loader`, since it was last updated 5 years ago.

Comment: Oops, I had it on the earlier versions of the app and didn't notice it wasn't updated since so long ago. I changed it but i get the same error when reading the "const".

Answer (score 0):

`ts-loader 6.x.x` is not compatible with `webpack 5.x.x`. Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#compatibility) `ts-loader 9.x.x` needs to be used with `webpack 5.x.x`.

Please try to update the `ts-loader` to the latest version. It might not solve the problem fully, but lets give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I upgraded ts-loader to 9.2.5 but i get the same error. I'll update the package.json on the question.

Answer (score 0):

From your error, your issue is definitely with the ts files, as it states "error in `./src/test.ts`"

Please update `ts-loader` to version 9, as github [Compatibility documentation for ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#compatibility) states:

> TypeScript: 3.6.3+
>
> webpack: 5.x+ (please use ts-loader 8.x if you need webpack 4 support)
>
> node: 12.x+

Also further [Research states](https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2021/04/20/ts-loader-goes-webpack-5/) the following:

> The minimum webpack version supported is now webpack 5. This simplifies the codebase, which previously had to if/else the various API registrations based on the version of webpack being used.
> The minimum node version supported is now node 12

According to [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/) that states:

> Webpack 5 requires at least Node.js 10.13.0 (LTS)
>
> Upgrade webpack-cli to the latest available version (when used)

So to be clear:

`ts-loader` - to be updated to version 9 minimum.

`node` - to be updated to version 12 minimum.

I notice your using 2 loaders for ts, I'm not sure whether the `angular2-template-loader` is supported for webpack 5, as it was last published 5 years ago according to the [angular2-template-loader documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-template-loader).

From looking at [webpack Integration documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/integrations/), specifically for integration using `karma` it says you can add webpack configuration within `karma.config`. So it leads me to believe that it might be struggling to read your `webpack.config`. could you try updating your `karma.config` specifically the `webpack` key to the below:

```js
 webpack: {
      resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules']
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    }
```

I've added the [resolve - modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules) to the `webpack` key as it:

> Tells webpack what directories should be searched when resolving modules.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I upgraded ts-loader to 9.2.5 but i get the same error. I'll update the package.json on the question.

Comment: It changes the results but now gives "ERROR in ./src/*whatever*.spec.ts 3:0-54 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve *whatever* in ./home/user/*whatever*" for every import in every .spec.ts (or so it seems). I'll update the post. Thank you!

Comment: Can you update the `webpack` key i've added the resolve to look through `node_modules`

Comment: Thanks! It still gives the same error. Maybe I explained myself wrongly. The error it gives about not finding X module is about my own components, modules and services not the ones imported from node_modules.

Comment: Is there a github or stackblitz example I could possibly see please?

Comment: I'll prepare a github example if i have time tomorrow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here's the example giving the same error: https://github.com/OriolInvernonLlaneza/karma-webpack-error-example

Comment: I've got a little bit further with this, seems to be something in the `karma.conf` as when i add `'src/app/app.component.ts',` to the `files` key that error goes and your `external.service` becomes an error. I tried the pattern of `ts` files but it didn't find all the necessary modules. I Also played around with the `alias` key within `module resolve` to see if that helped but I think theres something else that I might be missing.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I knew it had to be something with karma or the webpack config caused by the upgrade of Angular and Webpack. This is something that everytime that I'm forced to change it I need to seek help because I don't really grasp how they work and how should I configurate them.